# debezium content based routing configuration

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using confluent so I've installed dibezium connectors according to confluent docs using confluent-hub in connect.properties I do have entry

`plugin.path=/usr/share/java,/opt/confluent-6.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components`

I need to use io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/configuration/content-based-routing.html

so according to debezium doc I've downloaded `debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar`
and put it into
/opt/confluent-6.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components/ and copied it into
/opt/confluent-6.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-sqlserver/lib directories
here the entries in my mysql_src.json connector

```
"transforms": "unwrap,route",
"transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
"transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "source.snapshot",
"transforms.route.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter",
"transforms.route.language": "jsr223.groovy",
"transforms.route.topic.expression": "value.__source_snapshot == 'false' ? 'test'"
```

when I'm trying to configure/load this connector I'm getting following error message

```
[2020-12-15 22:18:45,351] ERROR [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=connect-cluster] Failed to reconfigure connector's tasks, retrying after backoff: (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder:1369)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException
```

Any suggestions how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Did you follow this step: Obtain a JSR-223 script engine implementation and add its contents to the Debezium plug-in directories of your Kafka Connect environment.?

Comment: copied debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar into /usr/share/java same error messsage

Comment: You need to install both debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar and JSR-223 script engine implementation (For example, for Groovy 3, you can download its JSR 223 implementation from https://groovy-lang.org/.)

Comment: I assume that debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar has all necessary components. could you point me to right docs/example how to it ?

Comment: From the docs: https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/configuration/content-based-routing.html#set-up-content-based-routing - please check steps 1 and 3.

Comment: > Debezium does not come with any implementations of the JSR 223 API. To use an expression language with Debezium, _you must download the JSR 223 script engine implementation_ for the language ...

Answer (score 0):

According the [docs](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.3/configuration/content-based-routing.html#set-up-content-based-routing), you need to additionally obtain a JSR-223 script engine implementation and add its contents to the Debezium plug-in directories of your Kafka Connect environment, since:

> Debezium does not come with any implementations of the JSR 223 API. To use an expression language with Debezium, you must download the JSR 223 script engine implementation for the language, and add to your Debezium connector plug-in directories, along any other JAR files used by the language implementation.

Comment: not likely it JSR 223, I've copied groovy-jsr223-3.0.7-indy.jar into /opt/confluent-6.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-debezium-connector-sqlserver/lib and still getting the same error,
I've commented out groovy part from connector.properties
transforms=unwrap,route
transforms.unwrap.type=io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState
transforms.unwrap.add.fields=source.snapshot
transforms.route.type=io.debezium.transforms.ContentBasedRouter
#transforms.route.language=jsr223.groovy
#transforms.route.topic.expression=value.snapshot == 'false' ? 'test' : null
still getting error

Comment: Did you restart Kafka Connect after this?

Comment: yes I did,connect log:
```[2020-12-16 08:01:13,649] INFO Loading plugin from: /opt/confluent-6.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:246)
[2020-12-16 08:01:13,655] INFO Registered loader: PluginClassLoader{pluginLocation=file:/opt/confluent-6.0.0/share/confluent-hub-components/debezium-scripting-1.3.1.Final.jar} (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.DelegatingClassLoader:269)```

Comment: I'm using confluent local CLI, could it be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that configuration is correct but I passed first configuration problem (I hope) I'm facing another problem now which I will describe in different question.
I am not sure what was wrong, I did following

1. Clean up zookeeper directories
2. Clean up kafka directories
3. Run kafka in distributed mode using command line start/stop scripts (not using confluent cli)
   this solved `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/debezium/DebeziumException`
   error